# Scripting using auturn

Tags: registry, key

I have a VBScript that runs a .reg file (I do this so the user cant see it running)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "regedit /s C:\Users\John\Desktop\OpenPorts.reg" ,1 ,True
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

which then runs the .reg file below

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR]
"Start" == dword:00000003
```

Can I combine this process into 1 VBScript that will make the changes without using a .reg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR\Start", 3, "REG_DWORD"
```

Comment: Gives me an error.

Line  :     3
Char  :     1
Error :     Invalid root in registry key "HKLM\SYSTEM|CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR\Start".
Code  :     80070005
Source:     WshShell.RegWrite

Comment: Ok, got it, it's an acces right problem. I don't have the solution at the moment. But if you can run your script as admin it should work. Interesting question anyway, i'll have a look on it. If i find a way to get rights from the script i'll post here. As often, it's not as trivial as it looks first :)
I'm sorry i can't do better for now.

Comment: I've found [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/185/1/VBScripts-and-UAC-elevation.html)
I've tested "method 1" and it worked for me. I hope it will for you :)

Comment: I tested method 1 again and put the value 3 in " " and it worked.
Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, i'v never tested it, but msdn says it's ok, so :)
Here is some doc with a little sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: I checked it out but no avail. As I said I am new to scripting so I don't think I did it correctly. It also seems as if that is to create a reg key, read it or delete it not change its value.